# Calculating a distance matrix based on spatial link distances (aka neighbor distances)

Tags: r, geospatial, distance-matrix

I would like to calculate a distance matrix between the centroids of the polygons in a region considering spatial link distance (aka 'neighbor distances') instead of simple Euclidean distances. Spatial link distance considers the Euclidean distances along the links of spatial neighbor links.

In other words, I would like to calculate spatial distance link matrix. Is there a package / function to do this?

I've done a quick exploration with [sfdep](https://r-spatial.github.io/spdep/reference/nbdists.html) and here's the solution I've found in the repex below:

## reprex

Step 1: calculate distances between neighboring polygons (`dists`) using `sfdep::st_nb_dists()`:

```
library(sf)
library(sfdep)
library(data.table)
library(fields)

# get contiguity and distance btwn neighbors
geo <- sf::st_geometry(guerry)
nb <- sfdep::st_contiguity(geo)
dists <- sfdep::st_nb_dists(geo, nb)
```

Step 2: I've created a `nb_list_to_df()` function to convert `dists` into a `data.frame` in long format with the distance for every pair or neighboring polygons (`od_df`)

```
# fun to convert nb dist to a data.frame in long format
nb_list_to_df <- function(nb, dists) {
  
  mtrx <- sfdep::wt_as_matrix(nb, dists)
  
  matrix_length <- 1:length(mtrx[1,])
  
  # FULL MATRIX
  mtrx_long <- cbind(
    as.data.table(
      data.table::CJ(matrix_length, matrix_length)), # df two columns
    'dist' = as.vector(mtrx)  # matrix values in a vector
  )
  
  # keep only dist between neighbors
  mtrx_long <- subset(mtrx_long, dist >0)
  setnames(mtrx_long, c('from', 'to', 'dist'))
  
  return(mtrx_long)
}

# convert nb dist to a data.frame in long format
od_df <- nb_list_to_df(nb, dists)
head(od_df)
#>    orig dest     dist
#> 1:    1   36 90030.63
#> 2:    1   37 87399.28
#> 3:    1   67 55587.69
#> 4:    1   69 85693.43
#> 5:    2    7 85221.38
#> 6:    2   49 75937.49
```

The final steps are to:

3. Use `od_df` to create a network graph using a library like `igraph`. In this case, I'm using `cppRouting` because it seems to be the most efficient.
4. Use the network topology to calculate the distance between all combinations of origin-destination pairs

```
# step 3: create a network graph
library(cppRouting)
graph  <-  makegraph(od_df, directed = F)

# step 4: get the distances considering network topology
dist_link <- get_distance_matrix(Graph=graph, 
                    from = unique(od_df$orig), 
                    to = unique(od_df$orig))
```

This code arrives at the desired solution. However, I'm wondering if this is a good approach or if there are better / more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are concerned that expanding the `nb` object to a matrix would demand too much RAM, which means finding a different solution to the first part of your code.
Here's a version without expanding the `nb` object into a matrix:

```r
library(sf)
library(sfdep)
library(data.table)

# get contiguity and distance between neighbors
geo = sf::st_geometry(guerry)
nb = sfdep::st_contiguity(geo)
dists = sfdep::st_nb_dists(geo, nb)


# If you look at the structure of nb, it's a list the lenght of
# nrow(geo) and each element contains the index of the neighbours
# of each row.
str(nb)
#> List of 85
#>  $ : int [1:4] 36 37 67 69
#>  $ : int [1:6] 7 49 57 58 73 76
#>  $ : int [1:6] 17 21 40 56 61 69
#>  $ : int [1:4] 5 24 79 80
#>  ---
#>  $ : int [1:6] 15 34 35 47 75 83
#>  $ : int [1:6] 15 18 21 22 34 82
#>  $ : int [1:6] 50 52 53 65 66 68
#>  $ : int [1:5] 9 19 43 56 73
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "nb" "list"
#>  - attr(*, "region.id")= chr [1:85] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>  - attr(*, "call")= language spdep::poly2nb(pl = geometry, queen = queen)
#>  - attr(*, "type")= chr "queen"
#>  - attr(*, "sym")= logi TRUE
# The same goes for dists
str(dists)
#> List of 85
#>  $ : num [1:4] 90031 87399 55588 85693
#>  $ : num [1:6] 85221 75937 125737 86797 102273 ...
#>  $ : num [1:6] 85461 92563 96614 88010 66400 ...
#>  $ : num [1:4] 53294 98250 83762 83974
#> ---
#>  $ : num [1:6] 110004 84644 69201 108549 60336 ...
#>  $ : num [1:6] 89353 81323 69322 96794 102964 ...
#>  $ : num [1:6] 85539 90350 116728 95918 71842 ...
#>  $ : num [1:5] 65601 96398 100014 82309 95857
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "nbdist" "list"
#>  - attr(*, "call")= language spdep::nbdists(nb = nb, coords = x, longlat = longlat)

# convert nb dist to a data.frame in long format
# You can loop through geo's row and collect destinations and distances as you go
n = length(nb)
res = data.table(from = integer(), to = integer(), dist = numeric())
for(i in seq_len(n)){
  res = rbind(res, data.table(from = i, to = nb[[i]], dist = dists[[i]]))
}
res
#>      from to      dist
#>   1:    1 36  90030.63
#>   2:    1 37  87399.28
#>   3:    1 67  55587.69
#>   4:    1 69  85693.43
#>   5:    2  7  85221.38
#>  ---                  
#> 416:   85  9  65601.32
#> 417:   85 19  96397.60
#> 418:   85 43 100013.94
#> 419:   85 56  82308.90
#> 420:   85 73  95857.49
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This method appends a data.table to the initial null table at each iteration, it's probably not super fast but should be RAM efficient. It can be optimised if you run into speed problems.

Comment: Thanks Duccio. It's a very elegant solution to the initial part of the problem. Your for loop arrives at the same result as the `nb_list_to_df()` function I proposed

Comment: @rafa.pereira For the second part, I can try to help but I am not sure what the problem is. You are using some jargon that I don't understand because I am not an expert on those topics and your final question concerns only the first part. Perhaps an example of the final results that you want to achieve and a specific question. Can you achieve what you want with those methods and you just want to optimise or do you need a solution to the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code I presented in the questions arrives at the desired output, but now I see I should edit the question to make this clearer

Comment: The second part of the question is about performance. The only way to go is to benchmark different implementations of your code (like, as you said, by using `igraph`, or `network` or `tidygraph`). Also, have a look at `cugraph` of rapids.ai, to run network analysis on GPU. They have a Python implementation but I vaguely remember seeing an R implementation, too.